# Paste files with the same names from directories and subdirectories to another directory

Tags: zsh, file-management

I'm looking for a way to paste files with the same names, contained in directories and subdirectories, to another directory with the same subdirectory structure.

For instance :

```
Dir1/a/a/file1
Dir2/a/a/file1
```

Those would be pasted into this directory :

```
Dir3/a/a/file1
```

Now I found on stackexchange a piece of zsh code that I modified to get the following :

```
#!/bin/zsh

typeset -A files
for file (dir*/*/*/*(nN)) files[$file:t]+=$file$'\0'
for file (${(k)files}) paste -d "\0" ${(0)files[$file]} > outputDir/*/*/$file
```

This doesn't work, as the code doesn't understand the "*" after outputDir. If I set a precise set of subdirectories for instance ouputDir/a/a/$file it works like a charm. I don't really know zsh as I discovered it with this piece of code. How could I do to keep the same subdirectories structure for the output dir ?

Thank you for your help.
Regards

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us a bit more detail. Does the `Dir3/a/a/` already exist? Which of the two original files do you want to keep? You cannot have two files with the same name in the same directory, so you will need to keep one of the two.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry for the lack of clarity. I need to perform paste command on files that share the same name in different directories but with the exact same subdirectory structure. I won't keep the two original files afterwards. For instance if file1 on dir1/a/a has one line with "hello" and the file1 on dir2/a/a has one line with "world", i want the newly created file in the (existing but empty) dir3/a/a to have one line containing "helloworld". I would like the code to automatically create the file in the same subdirectory than the two original files.

Comment: What do you mean with “paste” in this context? Please be more specific, but don’t answer here; update your question.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you rather want:

```
#! /bin/zsh -

typeset -A files
for file (dir*/*/*/*(nN)) files[${file#*/}]+=$file$'\0'
for file (${(k)files}) {
  mkdir -p outputDir/$file:h &&
    paste -d '\0' ${(0)files[$file]} > outputDir/$file
}
```

That is for the keys in that `A`ssociative array to be the paths of the files minus the first-level directory component rather than the basename (`t`ail) of the file.